# How to serialize in .NET MessagePack and deserialize in Node.js

Tags: c#, node.js, msgpack, lz4

I have a RabbitMQ queue and  two applications. First application is written in .NET core to generate send the payload to queue and the second one is in Node.js to read from the queue.

**Producer Application**

I use [MessagePack-CSharp](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) to serialize and compress (LZ4) the payload. Here is the serialization code in .NET:

```
using MessagePack;

namespace uBeac.Serialization
{
    public class MessageSerilizer
    {
        public static byte[] Serialize(object message)
        {
            MessagePackSerializer.SetDefaultResolver(MessagePack.Resolvers.ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance);
            return LZ4MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer Application**

I am reading the bytes in Node.js using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) library as below:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://...................', function (err, conn) {
    conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
        var queueName = 'toProcessor';
        ch.assertQueue(queueName, { durable: false });
        ch.prefetch(1);
        console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queueName);
        ch.consume(queueName, function (msg) {
            var secs = msg.content.toString().split('.').length - 1;
            console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(" [x] Done");
                ch.ack(msg);
            }, secs * 1000);
        }, { noAck: false });
    });
});
```

I have tried to deserialize the payload to Json object using some MsgPack libraries like [messagepack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/messagepack), [msgpack-node](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-node), ... But, it seems that they don't provide the same library in .NET as I showed above.

**Question:**  How can I decompress and deserialize the payload to Json object?

Comment: If you are compressing to LZ4 as a _binary stream_, what makes you think you can deserialise it via a _JSON_ library?

Comment: @MickyD I tried to so that using #lz4js: lz4.decompress(msg.content) , but it throws throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Comment: Then maybe better to fix _that error_ than trying something that may not work at all?

Comment: I did not get into how it serialize and compress in MessagePack to reverse it in Node.js. I thought that MessagePack is a solution which works in multiple languages with the same functionalities.

Comment: Your `Producer` is clearly serializing in **binary** and your `Consumer` deserializing as **string**.  That's not going to work.  My advice is to follow general enterprise messaging best practices and have your message content as `text` and **not** binary, therefore no explicit manual compression in the content.  Binary encoding places certain assumptions on the part of the receiver and reduces your audience not to mention you are more than likely going to break consumers with future changes.   Now if it is `text` you are not locked to any one vendor to encode/decode objects.

Comment: As I want to  pass object with different properties, I am serializing that. Do you mean that I should serialize it to Json string?

Comment: Serialize as `text`. Whether that is XML; JSON or something else is up to you